# Way to rewrite only first 30 chars using std::ofstream?

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream, overwrite, ofstream

is there a way to rewrite only the first 30 characters of a text file using std::ofstream without clearing all the other contents of a text file? I looked in the web, but that didn't help. One guy offered to rewrite the entire file, but that's very unefficient (there are +900*30 other characters). Anyone? Oh, and here's my code:

```
void Unlock(int Level)
{
    ifstream CheckIfExists("levels.txt");
    if (!CheckIfExists.good())
    {
        SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox(SDL_MESSAGEBOX_ERROR, "ERROR",
                                 "Unable to open the levels file. Next level won't be unlocked!", window);
        CheckIfExists.close();
        return;
    }
    CheckIfExists.close();
    if(Level >= 0 && Level <= 29)
    {
        ofstream New_Locks("levels.txt");
        Locked[Level] = UNLOCKED;
        for(int i = 0; i < 30; ++i) New_Locks << Locked[i];
        New_Locks.close();
        return;
    }
    else SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox(SDL_MESSAGEBOX_INFORMATION, "Congratulations!",
                                  "You won! Thank you for playing! Maybe once more?", window);
    return;
}
```

Comment: I need first 30 chars to be **completely overwriten** with the new ones. Otherwise next time program starts it will crash because of bad information order (additional 30 chars at the start). The number of non-whitespace characters in "levels.txt" must be a constant. EDIT: why did you delete your comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `fstream` instead of `ofstream`

`ifstream` is for reading only, `ofstream` for writing only, `fstream` does both.

Also note: it is not necessary to explicitly close the files. The fstream destructor will close them properly.

Comment: Wow, I didn't thought that the solution was THAT easy! Thank you so much! Problem solved!

Comment: If you've written to the stream, you'd better close it explicitly, so that you can check the status after the close, and report an error is need be.